# Instalar com PIP através do arquivo requirements.txt dentro do VirtualEnv?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Eu aprendi esses dias que, através do comando `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, eu posso gerar uma lista de dependências de um projeto específico onde estou usando `VirtualEnv`.

Como faço para instalar todas as bibliotecas contidas dentro desse arquivo `requirements.txt`, que eu exportei, através do comando `pip`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Iniciando o ambiente com as dependências

Resumindo, para criar um ambiente isolado para trabalhar com um projeto com as dependências definidas, basta seguir os passos:

1. Criar o novo ambiente:

   ```
   virtualenv ENV
   ```
2. Acessar o diretório do ambiente:

   ```
   cd ENV
   ```
3. Copiar o projeto para o diretório do ambiente, incluindo o arquivo `requirements.txt`;
4. Ativar o ambiente:

   ```
   bin/activate
   ```
5. Instalar as dependências do projeto:

   ```
   pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```
6. Trabalhar com o projeto, com todas as dependências instaladas no ambiente isolado;
7. Ao finalizar, desativar o ambiente:

   ```
   deactivate
   ```

---

Segue abaixo uma descrição mais detalhada de como funciona o `virtualenv` e os principais comandos para se trabalhar com um projeto em um ambiente isolado.

### Instalação

Utilizando o PIP, a instalação do VirtualEnv pode ser feita com um simples comando:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Se instalado com sucesso, uma mensagem semelhante aparecerá:

```
Successfully installed virtualenv-15.1.0
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Criação do ambiente

Para criar um ambiente isolado com o `virtualenv`, basta executar o comando:

```
virtualenv ENV
```

Sendo `ENV` o nome do ambiente a ser criado.

> No Windows, o comando é levemente alterado para `virtualenv.exe ENV`.

O resultado deste comando será um diretório de nome `ENV` no caminho atual, contendo as seguintes pastas:

```
bin/
include/
lib/
```

No Windows, será:

```
Include/
Lib/
Scripts/
```

Os diretórios `lib` e `include` armazenarão as bibliotecas instaladas no ambiente, enquanto o diretório `bin` armazena os executáveis que controlam o ambiente. No Windows, os diretórios `Lib` e `Include` são os equivalentes aos `lib` e `include`, respectivamente, enquanto o diretório `Scripts` é equivalente ao `bin`. As bibliotecas `pip` e `setuptools` já serão instaladas por padrão no ambiente criado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Instalando pacotes

Para adicionar os pacotes ao novo ambiente, é necessário fazer a instalação a partir do `pip` do ambiente e não mais do original do computador. O executável do `pip` do ambiente se encontra no diretório `bin`, portanto, para instalar um pacote, Django, por exemplo, é necessário fazer:

```
bin/pip install django
```

Ou, no Windows:

```
Scripts/pip install django
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Ativando o ambiente

Para evitar qualquer confusão entre o ambiente global, o próprio computador, e o ambiente isolado criado, é possível ativar o ambiente através do comando:

```
source bin/activate
```

Ou, no Windows:

```
Scripts/activate.bat
```

Este comando altera o valor da variável de ambiente `$PATH` para o diretório `bin` ou `Scripts`, no Windows. Desta forma, se o ambiente estiver ativado, para instalar um pacote, basta executar o comando padrão:

```
pip install django
```

Se executado tudo corretamente, apareceria uma mensagem dizendo que o pacote Django já está instalado, pois instalamo-o através do `Scripts/pip`.

É importante, ao terminar o trabalho no ambiente isolado que foi ativado, que o mesmo seja desativado para que seja restaurado o valor da variável de ambiente `$PATH`. Para isso, basta executar o comando:

```
deactivate
```

Ou, no Windows:

```
deactivate.bat
```

### Dependências do projeto

Com o ambiente isolado ativado, é possível gerar o arquivo de dependências a partir do comando:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado deste comando será o arquivo `requirements.txt` com a descrição das dependências do projeto. Neste caso:

```
Django==1.11.2
```

Para instalar as dependências de um projeto no ambiente isolado, basta executar:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Sensacional! muito obrigado pela resposta bem trabalhada!

Answer (score 2):

Conforme a [documentação](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/) creio que seja algo como:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Só que não entendo de `VirtualEnv`, por isto não posso afirmar se é necessário algo mais.

Comment: Isso aí já explica a pergunta.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters desculpe não entendi

Comment: É que quando você ativa o virtual env, vc pode rodar os comandos como se fosse na cmd global

Comment: @WallaceMaxters acho que entendi, o virtualenv é para ter "vários python" em uma mesma máquina

Comment: Na verdade, o Virtualenv é para ter um ambiente isolado, onde você não precise de um Python global, e sim apenas o que você precisa. Isso ajuda a controlar as coisas.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters então creio que minha resposta esteja errada ou apenas parcialmente correta, falta a questão do virtualenv mesmo né? Vou instalar hoje e atualizo. Obrigado pela oportunidade de me deixar responder, sei que vc deve já saber a resposta xD

Comment: Não exatamente.

Answer (score 2):

O comando é `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Basta executar isso dentro de ambiente desejado e todas as bibliotecas contidas em `requirements.txt` serão instaladas.

Comment: Se você acha que a sua resposta será melhor, eu recomendaria no mínimo abordar a diferença entre executar o `pip` global e o do ambiente isolado. Essa informação é fundamental para responder a pergunta.

Comment: Sua resposta está muito melhor, mais completa. Porém tentei apenas dar uma outra alternativa que vá direto ao que foi perguntado, que pode (e foi) respondido em 3 linhas. Quanto a abordar a diferença entre pip global e pip dentro de virtualenv, isso não foi perguntado, por isso não escrevi.

Comment: O título da pergunta especifica que a instalação deve ocorrer em um ambiente isolado criado pelo `virtualenv`.

Comment: A sua resposta foi o mesmo que eu respondi (inclusive eu fui o primeiro a responder), o autor me falou que isto é apenas parte da resposta, a parte dos ambientes é muito importante, eu tinha deletado a resposta, mas restaurei somente para você poder ver os comentários https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/209388/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Nos comentários do autor ele mesmo diz "Na verdade, o Virtualenv é para ter um ambiente isolado, onde você não precise de um Python global, e sim apenas o que você precisa. Isso ajuda a controlar as coisas. – Wallace Maxters" Ou seja, ele sabe para que serve virtualenv e como ele mesmo disse na pergunta, ele está usando virtualenv, ou seja, ele sabe como ativá-lo. Se ele sabe para que serve e sabe como ativá-lo, só resta saber como instalar as bibliotecas né? (que foi a única coisa perguntada). E foi exatamente isso que eu escrevi. Entre no ambiente e execute o comando.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Pra concluir, você Guilherme, respondeu o que o autor perguntou. Eu respondi o que ele perguntou e mais um pouco. O Anderson respondeu o que eu respondi e mais ainda.

Comment: @gabrielbelini pode ser, é que eu conversei com o Wallace no chat e tive a impressão que faltava algo, vamos esperar ele (autor) confirmar, você pode estar certo :)