# Erro ao criar ambiente virtual mkvirtualenv python 3.6

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv, python

Após instalar o python 3.6 e depois o virtualenvwrapper via pip (pip instal virtualenvwrapper-win), tentei criar um ambiente virtual pelo comando "mkvirtualenv nome" e ocorreu o seguinte erro:

```
    λ mkvirtualenv django
    Using base prefix 
    'c:\\users\\joãopaulo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32'
    New python executable in 
    C:\Users\JoãoPaulo\Envs\django\Scripts\python.exe
    Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
    Complete output from command 
    C:\Users\JoãoPaulo\E...o\Scripts\python.exe - setuptools pip wheel:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkgutil'
    ----------------------------------------
    ...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\joãopaulo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-
    32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "c:\users\joãopaulo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-
    32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\JoãoPaulo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
    32\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
    File "c:\users\joãopaulo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-
    32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
    File "c:\users\joãopaulo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-
    32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
    download=download,
    File "c:\users\joãopaulo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-
    32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
    File "c:\users\joãopaulo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-
    32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
    OSError: Command C:\Users\JoãoPaulo\E...o\Scripts\python.exe - 
    setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Já tentei reinstalar o virtualenvwrapper, bem como refazer todo o processo, porem ele continua insistindo no erro, e eu não sei mais o que fazer, alguem pode me ajudar

Comment: Se voce não tiver um motivo que te obrigue a usar virtualenvwrapper. sugiro que [instale o anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) e acabe de vez com problemas de gerenciamento de envs.

Comment: obrigado pela dica, vou dar uma pesquisada nisso e se resolver posto aqui.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209384/5878

Answer (score 0):

A partir da versão `3.3` o `python` ja vem com o modulo `venv` que permite a criação de ambientes virtuais sem a necessidade de instalação de pacotes adicionais via `pip`.

Basta utilizar o comando `c:\Python35\python -m venv c:\path\to\myenv`

Para mais informações: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html