# Problemas ao tentar criar um ambiente virtual com pipenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Estou com dificuldades para criar um ambiente virtual com o *pipenv*, eu instalei ele sem problemas com o *pip*, o problema acontece na hora de criar o ambiente.
Estou utilizando o Windows 10 e o Python 3.7.

Eu tentei instalar o *pipenv* utilizando o comando:

```
pip install pipenv
```

A instalação não apresentou erros, mas deu problema ao tentar criar o ambiente. Então eu desinstalei tudo e tentei com:

```
pip install --user pipenv
```

Ajustando as variáveis de ambiente conforme explicado na documentação, mas também deu erro ao tentar criar o ambiente.
Tentei criar o ambiente virtual com os seguintes comandos:

```
pipenv install
pipenv install django
pipenv --three
```

O que me retorna:

```
    Creating a virtualenv for this project…
    Pipfile: C:\python\projeto\Pipfile
    Using c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe 
    (3.7.0) to create virtualenv…
    [=== ] Creating virtual environment...Already using interpreter 
    c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
    Using base prefix 
    'c:\\users\\usuário\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32'
    New python executable in C:\python\projeto\.venv\Scripts\python.exe
    Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
    Complete output from command C:\python\projeto\.venv\Scripts\python.exe - 
    setuptools pip wheel:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkgutil'
    ----------------------------------------
    ...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
    Failed creating virtual environment
    [pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File 
    "c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site- 
   packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 254, in install
    [pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       
    editable_packages=state.installstate.editables,
    [pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File 
    "c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site- 
   packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1741, in do_install
    [pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       
    pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
    [pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File 
    "c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site- 
   packages\pipenv\core.py", line 574, in ensure_project
    [pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       
    pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
    [pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File 
    "c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site- 
   packages\pipenv\core.py", line 506, in ensure_virtualenv
    [pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       python=python, 
    site_packages=site_packages, pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror
    [pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File 
    "c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site- 
   packages\pipenv\core.py", line 935, in do_create_virtualenv
    [pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       extra=[crayons.blue(" 
   {0}".format(c.err)),]
    [pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]: Traceback (most recent call 
    last):
    File "c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37- 
   32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37- 
   32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
    File "c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site- 
   packages\virtualenv.py", line 2462, in <module>
    main()
    File "c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site- 
   packages\virtualenv.py", line 762, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,
    File "c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site- 
   packages\virtualenv.py", line 1015, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs, download=download)
    File "c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site- 
   packages\virtualenv.py", line 968, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
    File "c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site- 
   packages\virtualenv.py", line 854, in call_subprocess
    raise OSError("Command {} failed with error code {}".format(cmd_desc, 
    proc.returncode))
    OSError: Command C:\python\projeto\.venv\Scripts\python.exe - setuptools pip 
    wheel failed with error code 1
    Failed to create virtual environment.
```

Essa pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220835/erro-ao-criar-ambiente-virtual-mkvirtualenv-python-3-6) não me ajudou muito nesse problema.

Alguém tem uma luz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou deixar aqui a solução que eu encontrei, pode ser útil para mais alguém.
Eu tentei criar um ambiente virtual direto com o *virtualenv*, já que o pipenv usa ele por baixo dos panos
*virtualenv .venv*
mas isso estava apresentando erro, até tentei reinstalar o pip e o virtualenv mas não funcionou. Como eu já usava o *venv* que vem por padrão no Python, resolvi o problema criando o ambiente através dele
*python -m venv .venv*
e a partir daí estou usando o *pipenv* normalmente sem problemas
*pipenv shell*
*pipenv install django*

É possível que nem tudo no *pipenv* funcione corretamente, mas para os comandos básicos de instalação e desinstalação de dependências, geração do pipfile e outras coisas que estou utilizando até o momento está funcionando sem problemas.

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma pergunta parecida com a sua no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305461/can-not-run-virtualenv-successfully-on-win10).

Lá é levantado que talvez vc tenha uma instalação quebrada do 'pip' e recomenda-se desisnstalar o pip e instalar novamente. 
Não sou muito fã desse tipo de resposta, mas pode ser que funcione no seu caso. 
Verifique também se você consegue instalar o ambiente virtual **sem usar** o pipenv, ou seja usando apenas o pip.

`pip install virtualenv`

Caso não consiga e ocorra o mesmo erro, é bem provavel que seja de fato um problema interno com os arquivos de sua versão do pip.

Uma ultima dica. 
Se vc vai trabalhar com Django , procure sempre usar uma versão estável do python. Vejo que esta usando python 3.7, no momento tem uma pequeno bug de compatibilidade entre algumas versões do django e o python 3.7.

Então, antecedendo possíveis problemas, caso ocorra um erro semelhante a [**esse**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822571/syntaxerror-generator-expression-must-be-parenthezised-python-manage-py-migra) o django tem um [fix](https://github.com/django/django/commit/931c60c5216bd71bc11f489e00e063331cf21f40) para o mesmo , sinta-se a vontade para usa-lo.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica da versão com o Django! Referente ao pipenv, percebi que o virtualenv dá esse problema, então tentei criar o ambiente usando venv e a princípio está funcionando bem.

Answer (score 0):

A dica acima foi perfeita! Parabéns e obrigado, @Gau

**Após desinstalar pipenv...**

```
 pip uninstall pipenv
```

**fiz...**

```
python -m venv .venv
```

**depois...**

```
pip install pipenv
```

**e na sequencia...**

```
pipenv shell

pipenv install selenium
```

**procedendo finalmente com a instalação desejada, eliminado assim com o *error code 1* recorrente**

```
 Installing selenium… Adding selenium to Pipfile's [packages]…
 Installation Succeeded Pipfile.lock not found, creating… Locking
 [dev-packages] dependencies… Locking [packages] dependencies… Success!
 Updated Pipfile.lock (2bb13d)! Installing dependencies from
 Pipfile.lock (2bb13d)…
```