# Não consigo usar schedule

Tags: python-3.x, scheduler

já executei o comando

```
pip install schedule
```

e o

```
pip3 install schedule
```

porém quando tento importar o schedule

```
import schedule
```

Aparece o seguinte erro:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'schedule'

O que devo fazer para funcionar?
Utilizo o python 3.7 no windows 10.

Comment: Executou o comando pip install com privilégios de administrador? Caso não, ele não vai conseguir instalar. Verifique a mensagem no final para ter certeza de que a foi instalado com sucesso.

Comment: Aparece aqui que foi instalado com sucesso.. "Successfully installed schedule-0.5.0"

Comment: se digitar `pip -V` o que o seu console mostra?

Comment: pip 18.1 from c:\pythons\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

Comment: Qual a saída de `pip show schedule`? E com `pip3`? Já cogitou utilizar [ambientes virtuais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209384/5878)?

Comment: Executando esse comando aparece os dados como nome, versão, etc. Já fiz com pip3 também, não mudou nada

Comment: scheduled funiona para Windows ?

Comment: funciona. Não sei o motivo de não funcionar. Do nada funcionou, e aconteceu a mesma coisa com o pandas. isso na maquina do meu trabalho e na pessoal, o mesmo problema.. igualzinho